# C++ making constructor for nested class

Tags: c++, class, constructor

Consider a class as the following:

```
class A {
    public:
    // code...

    private:
    class B {
        public:
        int aNum;
        // ...
    }
}
```

And I'm to make some constructors for A, such as:

```
A::A() { } // default...

A::A(int input) { /* code... */ }
```

So I'm wondering how to access     `aNum`, because it's not directly under A.

Comment: To access `aNum`, you would need an `A::B` object, which you haven't declared anywhere.

Comment: `B` is a class on its own, it's not a subset or dependency of A. The only difference between having `class B {` where it is, and having it outside of `A` entirely, is that you refer to the class via `A::B` instead of `::B`. (With associated access rights)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As some of the comments state, you can't just "access" `aNum` from `A` because it's part of `B`.

You either need to create a `B` object within `A` and set the value in the `B` object or you need to move `aNum` from `B` to `A`.

If you create a `B` object within `A` this would look something like this.

```
struct A {
    A(int input) {
        bObj.aNum = input;
    }

    // ...

private:
    struct B {
        int aNum;
        // ...
    };

    B bObj;
};
```

You should think about if `aNum` is really a part of a nested class if you like to access it from `A` directly. In such cases it's most likely that your class design is wrong and that `aNum` is really a part of `A` and not `B`.

Comment: I would give `B` its own constructor to initialize `aNum`, then `A`'s constructor can use its initializer list to initialize `bObj` : `A(int input) : bObj(input) {}`

Answer (score 0):

its like having any data member on your class, its no different

```
class A {
    public:
    // code...

    private:
    class B {
        public:
        int aNum;
    }
}
```

before you can access `aNum` which is a non-static data member of class `B` you have to create an object of type `B` like this:

```
class A
{
    public:
        const B& getObjectB() const { return objectB; }; 
    private:
        B objectB;
}
```

with that you can do like this:

```
A objectA;
objectA.getObjectB().aNum;
```

what happens here  is we call the `getObjectB()` which returns the `objectB` and then call `aNum` through that.

Answer (score 0):

A needs some way to refer to an object of type B, here is a simple example.

```
class A {
    private:
        class B {
        public:
            int aNum;
        };
        B b;
    public:
        A(int);
};
A::A(int input) {
    b.aNum = input;
}
```